# How to click box to show more rows on bottom of page?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to scrape a page with many rows of data. This data is spread across multiple pages with only 25 rows on each page unless a dropdown is changed at the bottom.

I have looked at regular class and name selections in Selenium and it has nothing as simple. It has class names but their are multiple names in the same class which find_by_class_name will not work with.

From my research I should use xpath however all my attempts below have failed.

I have also tried simply changing the page but the same issue appears where the buttons are not clickable without xpath and xpath will not work.

I have tried gathering the Xpath from xpath extensions to get it exactly right and Selenium still throws me an error.

This is a snippet of the html that is the dropdown I must click

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.limit" ng-options="pageSize as pageSize for pageSize in ctrl.pageSizeOptions" ng-change="ctrl.onPageSizeChange()" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" aria-invalid="false"><option label="25" value="number:25" selected="selected">25</option><option label="50" value="number:50">50</option><option label="100" value="number:100">100</option><option label="500" value="number:500">500</option></select>
```

and here is how it looks visually

[image: 0m7jlx]

This is the current xpath my extension is giving me and how I am feeding it into Selenium

```
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[@class=' geolocation svg localstorage sessionstorage audio canvas canvastext video webgl no-emoji inlinesvg supports svgclippaths smil nthchild cssanimations csscolumns csscolumns-width csscolumns-span csscolumns-fill csscolumns-gap csscolumns-rule csscolumns-rulecolor csscolumns-rulestyle csscolumns-rulewidth csscolumns-breakbefore csscolumns-breakafter csscolumns-breakinside cssfilters flexbox flexboxlegacy']/body[@class='nav-menu-open']/blocking-notifications/span/ng-transclude/content-with-sidebar[@class='content-and-sidebar']/div[@class='flex-main page-main']/main[@class='flex-section page-content ntux-wrapper sidebar-open--ntux']/div[@class='tester-app view-contents--ntux']/ng-transclude/content-slot/div[@class='view-contents']/ui-view/div[@class='testcycle main-page-content is-ttl']/div[@class='tab-content']/div[@class='testcase-list main-page-content']/responsive-table/div/div[@class='responsive-table-wrap']/div[@class='responsive-table-pagination']/span/select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched']"))
select.select_by_visible_text('500')
```

and the error is

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Expected - Element is selected and can be opened with further commands

Actual - I get an error stating that the element does not exist

Thanks for any help!

Comment: is the page available in public domain, if yes can u post the link?

Comment: @Ravi No sorry. It's the same as my last question. It's behind a wall.

Comment: You didn't actually selected anything, only created `select` object. For the error you can add [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: I didn't write the further code. Maybe I wasn't clear. The issue is that Selenium is stating the element does not exist. I have select.select_by_value('500') and tried your above with no success. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: It is the problem because of the element xpath you are providing, try with any previous element which has id tag and get the next element or try with partial class name

Comment: Are there multiple select boxes on page?

Comment: Sorted now @Ravi Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code see if it helps.

```
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty"))
select.select_by_visible_text("500")
```

OR.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty").send_keys(Keys.END)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Sorry @Kajal. I didn't write the further code. Maybe I wasn't clear. The issue is that Selenium is stating the element does not exist. I have select.select_by_value('500') and tried your above with no success. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: if you use selected by value it won't work.because value is not "500" it is "number:500" please check the html.

Comment: I have tried both. I think the issue is that the xpath is not correct to start with. That is where the error is appearing. That is why I did not include the select afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It would seem it still cannot find the element :/ ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"select.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty"}
```

Comment: The Html you have posted it is working fine in my laptop.Please provide some wait before accessing the element

Comment: Okay, i'll give this a go. One moment

Comment: Okay so your second example worked perfectly after the wait. Thanks so much for your help!